# pandas multiple plots not working as hists

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

with a dataframe df in Pandas, I am trying to plot histograms on the same page filtering by 3 different variables; the intended outcome is histograms of the values for each of the three types.  The following code works for me as PLOTs, but when I change to HISTs, they all stack on top of each other.  Any suggestions?

```
plt.figure(1)

plt.subplot(311)
df[df.Type == 'Type1'].values.plot()

plt.subplot(312)
df[df.Type == 'Type2'].values.plot()

plt.subplot(313)
df[df.Type == 'Type3'].values.plot()

plt.savefig('output.pdf')
```

Is this a bug in Pandas or are plot and hist not interchangable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show us an image of what your getting?  Or provide fake data so we can test this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot and hist aren't interchangabe: hist is its own [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html#pandas.DataFrame.hist) and [Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.hist.html#pandas.Series.hist) methods. You might be able to force the plots to be independent by passing in an ax keyword. So

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1)
df[df.Type == 'Type1'].values.hist(ax=ax1)
....
```