# Multiple histograms in Pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, histogram

I would like to create the following histogram (see image below) taken from the book "Think Stats". However, I cannot get them on the same plot. Each DataFrame takes its own subplot.

I have the following code:

```
import nsfg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = nsfg.ReadFemPreg()
preg = nsfg.ReadFemPreg()
live = preg[preg.outcome == 1]

first = live[live.birthord == 1]
others = live[live.birthord != 1]

#fig = plt.figure()
#ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

first.hist(column = 'prglngth', bins = 40, color = 'teal', \
           alpha = 0.5)
others.hist(column = 'prglngth', bins = 40, color = 'blue', \
            alpha = 0.5)
plt.show()
```

The above code does not work when I use ax = ax1 as suggested in: [pandas multiple plots not working as hists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080186/pandas-multiple-plots-not-working-as-hists?rq=1) nor this example does what I need: [Overlaying multiple histograms using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280336/overlaying-multiple-histograms-using-pandas). When I use the code as it is, it creates two windows with histograms. Any ideas how to combine them?

Here's an example of how I'd like the final figure to look:
[image]

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As far as I can tell, pandas can't handle this situation. That's ok since all of their plotting methods are for convenience only. You'll need to use matplotlib directly. Here's how I do it:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
#import seaborn
#seaborn.set(style='ticks')

np.random.seed(0)
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(37,2)), columns=['A', 'B'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

a_heights, a_bins = np.histogram(df['A'])
b_heights, b_bins = np.histogram(df['B'], bins=a_bins)

width = (a_bins[1] - a_bins[0])/3

ax.bar(a_bins[:-1], a_heights, width=width, facecolor='cornflowerblue')
ax.bar(b_bins[:-1]+width, b_heights, width=width, facecolor='seagreen')
#seaborn.despine(ax=ax, offset=10)
```

And that gives me:
[image]

Comment: In my case, this adds an offset to the data. That may not be appreciated in the example, since the data is random. However, I cannot figure out where is the bug

Comment: There is no bug that I can see. The width for each bin in the histogram is represented by the combined width of both bars. Not the clearest way to represent the data, but it behaves as expected. @kiril

Answer (score 25):

In case anyone wants to plot one histogram over another (rather than alternating bars) you can simply call `.hist()` consecutively on the series you want to plot:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas


np.random.seed(0)
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(37,2)), columns=['A', 'B'])

df['A'].hist()
df['B'].hist()
```

This gives you:

[image]

Note that the order you call `.hist()` matters (the first one will be at the back)

Comment: do you know how to label them?

Comment: How do I get it not to overlay like this?

Comment: adding `alpha` to the second plot makes both visible, e.g. `df['B'].hist(alpha=0.5)`

Comment: How to do that with multiple dimensions (columns) at once ?

Comment: Warning, this will not use the same bins for both plots. Since the histogram shape can be very sensitive to the bins, it may give a false impression of how your dataset
 compare.

Comment: @ChristianBueno can't you set bins as a kw argument and set it the same for both?

Answer (score 23):

A quick solution is to use `melt()` from `pandas` and then plot with `seaborn`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# make dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(200,2)), columns=['A', 'B'])

# plot melted dataframe in a single command
sns.histplot(df.melt(), x='value', hue='variable',
             multiple='dodge', shrink=.75, bins=20);
```

[image]

Setting `multiple='dodge'` makes it so the bars are side-by-side, and `shrink=.75` makes it so the pair of bars take up 3/4 of the whole bin.

To help understand what `melt()` did, these are the dataframes `df` and `df.melt()`:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

From the pandas website (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#visualization-hist):

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(1000) + 1, 'b': np.random.randn(1000),
                    'c': np.random.randn(1000) - 1}, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

plt.figure();

df4.plot(kind='hist', alpha=0.5)
```

Answer (score 8):

You make two dataframes and one matplotlib axis

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'data1': np.random.randn(10),
    'data2': np.random.randn(10)
})

df2 = df1.copy()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df1.hist(column=['data1'], ax=ax)
df2.hist(column=['data2'], ax=ax)
```

Comment: Is there a way to show the columns side by side instead of them overlapping?

Comment: This does not create a grouped bar histogram like the one that is shown in the question. This is actually an unnecessarily complicated version of the answer already provided by lin_bug.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the snippet, In my case I have explicitly specified bins and range as I didn't handle outlier removal as the author of the book.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist([first.prglngth, others.prglngth], 10, (27, 50), histtype="bar", label=("First", "Other"))
ax.set_title("Histogram")
ax.legend()
```

Refer Matplotlib multihist plot with different sizes [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_multihist.html).

Answer (score 4):

this could be done with brevity

```
plt.hist([First, Other], bins = 40, color =('teal','blue'), label=("First", "Other"))
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Note that as the number of bins increase, it may become a visual burden.

Comment: I wanted to believe... but this has the same problem that several other answers here do: the histograms are on top of each other, not interleaved.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to check out the `pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist()` function which will plot the histogram of each column of the dataframe in the same figure.
Visibility is limited though but you can check out if it helps!
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html